# How to run a python program in Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, window, atom-editor

I am getting as such error for executing my hello world program:

> "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action"

[image: execution attempt screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Download the official version of **[Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/python-3.8.1-amd64.exe)**

**2)** Use custom installation following the screenshots bellow.

**3)** Run your **`hello.py`** file directly from the command line by typing **`hello.py`**

- **Screenshots #1**

  ---

[image]

- **Screenshots #2**

  ---

[image]

- **Screenshots #3**

  ---

[image]

---

- I have this python code that I'm running on just by typing Q60471933.py

```py
from datetime import datetime
print("\nHello World\n",datetime.now().strftime("\b%m/%d/%Y\n%H:%M:%S"))
```

---

- Outputs:
  [image]

  ---

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your command prompt:

```
python3 hello.py
```